# Fixing an issue of deletion within Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework, asynchronous

I have this method :

```
 public async void Delete(params T[] items)
 {
     using (var context = new DataEntities())
     {
         foreach (T item in items)
         {
             context.Entry(item).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted;
         }

         await context.SaveChangesAsync();
     }
}
```

When I tried to delete an item :

```
dpc_participant part = (await SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<ICrud<dpc_participant>>().Search(x => x.dpc_id_participant_pk == currentitem.dpc_id_participant_pk && x.dpc_id_fk == currentitem.dpc_id_pk)).FirstOrDefault();
SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<ICrud<dpc_participant>>().Delete(part);
```

I got this error

> entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.

Questions:

1. What is the reason of this error?
2. How can I fix it?

Comment: your parameters came from a different Database Context, than the one you're creating here.  Disable proxies on the source context and see if that does the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because your items variable is connected to a different context than the context your function is using.

To Fix, either pass the original context you retrieved the items with into this function and use it or re-query them using the new context within the function and then delete.